# Single transaction per request with Spring MVC and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, open-session-in-view

I want to use Spring MVC and Hibernate. I don't want to use service layer or `@Transactional` attribute on all controller methods (or, rather, I want Spring to treat them all as transactional). So I want to start transaction when controller method starts to work with database and commit transaction when controller method returns ViewAndModel or rollback transaction if any error occured. Also I want view to support lazy hibernate loading, e.g. select data in an autocommit mode if html template requests that.

I'm aware that best practice involves creating a separate service layer with `@Transactional` attribute, but my application won't benefit from that additional complexity and I want to simplify code as much as possible.

I've learned that `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` allows to continue using hibernate session in view, so that probably solves my second requirement. But how do I make all controller methods transactional?

Ideally I want an easy way to opt-out from this behaviour if I ever would need that. E.g. all methods are transactional, yet I can apply something like @NonTransactional and manage transactions more granularly.

Comment: Have you considered using Spring AOP ?

Comment: Yes, I don't know it very well, but researching it now. I hoped for some simple solution as this task seems to be quite typical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` will open a session (and implicitly a transaction) before any of your controller code starts and close it just before the http request is completed. So it should solve both your requirements.

See [source](https://github.com/joshlong/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-orm-hibernate4/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/support/OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.java)

The same is true for `OpenEntityManagerInView`.